# Display Flex Centre & Bottom

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm trying to create a full height header and have one element centre and another element at the bottom.

I have always used `position: absolute;` to do this, but I would like to use `flex` instead.

```css
.full-header {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}

.align-item-center {
  background-color: blue;
}

.align-item-end {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container full-header">
  <div class="align-item-center">
    Row 1
  </div>
  <div class="align-item-end">
    Row 2
  </div>
</div>
```

I have attached a diagram to help communicate what I'm trying to do. I am also using bootstrap 4, although if someone can point me in the direction of native flex, that would also be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

- Set the `flex-direction` of `.full-header` to `column`. This will order the child `div`s from top to bottom
- Add an automatic top and bottom `margin` to `.align-item-center`. This will ensure that the top and bottom `margin`s of `.align-item-center` will automatically extend to occupy the available space in `.full-header`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.full-header {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.align-item-center {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.align-item-end {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container full-header">
  <div class="align-item-center">
    Row 1
  </div>
  <div class="align-item-end">
    Row 2
  </div>
</div>
```